# Can't connect to freshly installed MongoDB

Tags: windows, mongodb, terminal

I'm rather new to MongoDB and installed it recently using the MongoDB community server (On my Windows clinet). I set the environment variable and started the database using `mongod`. Everything seemed fine and I can connect to the database using the GUI of Robo3T.

But if I try to connect to the DB using the `mongo` command in the Terminal I get the following Error:

`Failed global initialization: InvalidSSLConfiguration CertCreateCertificateChainEngine failed: Falscher Parameter.`

Seems like some SSL configuration failed, but I never touched anything in the configuration file of Mongo. What can I do to connect to my database in the terminal?

It turnes out, that I get that error no matter if I try to connect to the local DB or some other IP on another Server. So I'm pretty sure the error is not caused by my local mongodb server.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is it possible you have more than one mongod running on different ports where one has SSL enabled and the other doesn't?

Comment: I had a installation previously but since it had some flaws, I uninstalled it and (tried to) removed all configurations for it. But it could be that I left something laying around from the old installation...
I also get the error if I try to connect to an external mongoDB, so it probably has nothing to do with the local database installation.

Comment: can we see the command line that you ran to get the invalid SSL error?  You might also try running mongo with --verbose to get more detail.

Comment: I just ran "mongo" which according to the docs should be able to connect to the local server running without authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I completely stopped the mongo service, removed every single file I was able to find containing mongo information. Reboot my system and install mongo anew. That was the only way I was able to fix it, since just uninstalling and reinstalling didn't do the trick.